# Doxygen adding \+ in between capital letters

Tags: doxygen

I am using doxygen to generate a .tex file which I then turn into a pdf using MikTex Texworks.

In my main.cpp file, I added some comments which include capital words such as SNMP and FTP.  When Doxygen generate the refman.tex it add \+ in between each letter.

Example:  S\+N\+M\+P

Any idea as to what could be causing this? I am using doxygen1.8.14 and Texworks 0.6.2 (MikTek 2.9.6615).

I am having to open the refman.tex file and remove all \+ before I can convert the file into pdf.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is off-topic for the site. Can you please add a small example of a document that produces the issue?

Comment: doxygen is adding these characters to be able to hyphenate in case of e.g. theFunction at the F. For words, in running texts, completely in capitals this is a bit unwanted. Problems, can, occur when variable names are written completely in capitals and they are not hyphenated.

Comment: Albert, any idea on how I can stop(correct) this behavior?